# How can I import Photoshop layer with a mask to After effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, layers, mask, adobe-after-effects

I've prepared a layer with a mask in Photoshop and I want to use it in After effects. What I want to do is add a video on to that prepared layer and mask it.

Comment: So you want the video to show beneath your mask?  I would save your PS file as a transparent png then just overlay that above your video.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, but I wanted to find out if layers with masks are working in AE or is it just this one way around.